# Reassigning File Associations For Dreamweaver?

Tags: windows, dreamweaver

How can I reassign the file extensions for Dreamweaver?

I installed Microsoft Expression to play around with, and all my `.php`, `.css`, etc files are now associated with it. I tried holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or whatever it is to reset Dreamweaver, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-install Dreamweaver or do a repair installation.

Windows itself doesn't keep track of previous file associations (to my knowledge). The only thing that comes close is system restore. But I don't think you need to go to such lengths. Repair installation should do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Or just open the file's properties in windows and Change 'Opens with' to Dreamweaver app.

If the app isn't listed, Browse to... (Dreamweaver.exe)

EDIT:
In Dreamviewer CC, goto: Edit > Preferences > File types / Editors <<< there you go. If the appropriate checkboxes are checked, uncheck and apply, then check them again and apply.

Comment: You could, but then you'd have to go through every file type that you want associated with the application and change it. And then if you accidentally set it on the wrong file, you get an ugly DW icon instead of a nice file icon. Not a big deal, I'm just very particular.

Comment: Terrible answer. Dreamweaver resets the file association every now and then. Then you'll have to do this step over again, and over again, and over again. In general, Dreamweaver is a terrible program if you're only using it for ninche things.

Comment: In Dreamviewer CC, goto: Edit > Preferences > File types / Editors <<< there you go. If the appropriate checkboxes are checked, uncheck and apply, then check them again and apply.